# CDN REST doesn't give the path

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx

I'm trying to get the public CDN path for my JS file like this:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/publiccdn.ashx/url?itemurl=https://contoso.sharepoint.com/CDN/script.js
```

But the result I have is

> `"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/CDN/script.js"`

In PowerShell I'm able to get the ID for that CDN folder like so:

```
$creds = Get-Credential

Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credential $creds

Get-SPOPublicCdnOrigins
```

But I wonder why the API REST doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did your issue get resolved? I am facing same issue

Comment: "we are in progress of pushing some updates around the CDN capability as part of the journey for the GA, which will be impacting both documentation and existing configurations. We should have more detailed information on the updated configuration and behaviour in matter of few weeks."

that is what Vesa said.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of same origin policy in SharePoint that is preventing a domain outside SharePoint from loading. The same origin policy is adapted to prevent clickjack attacks. If you see, you wont be able to load pages outside SharePoint in an iframe too.

Not only SharePoint but most of the sites implemented same origin policy now

Comment: The file I'm trying to get is inside of my domain